# Google Calendar API Insert Event using Android

Tags: android, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have followed https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples to insert a new Event but I encounter a problem at this line:

```
event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
```

When I debug to above line, the app force closes and I don't know the problem...

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace from Logcat?

Comment: this is reason i catched: 
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden { "code" : 403, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Insufficient Permission", "reason" : "insufficientPermissions" } ], "message" : "Insufficient Permission" }

Comment: You need to authenticate yourself before inserting events

Comment: Pls tell me how to autheticate, I'm new with Auth ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Pls tell me how to autheticate, I'm new with Auth

To authenticate with Calendar API, you'll be needing to enable the Calendar API in your GDC. After that you'll need to generate an OAuthClientID for Android. You'll also be defining a scope wether you want to read, write, or do both. Here's the full [Setup Process](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth).

When you're done with oAuth setup, you'll be [adding several dependencies in your Android Project](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android#step_1_acquire_a_sha1_fingerprint)

Try the [full sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/calendar-android-sample)

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! it's useful for me, i'm had mistake at scope.

Comment: @JuT.Jun Glad I was of help. An upvote or accepting the answer will do.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was also the scope so the solution for those who don't know how is:

Change this

```
private static final String[] SCOPES = { CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY };
```

for this

```
private static final String[] SCOPES = { CalendarScopes.CALENDAR };
```

And now you can initialize credentials

```
// Initialize credentials and service object.
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
```